# How to include txtai repository as a dependency in requirements.txt?

Tags: python, heroku, dependencies, streamlit, requirements.txt

I have developed a streamlit webapp and I want to deploy it on Heroku. The project has the following requirements.txt file

```
streamlit==1.10.0
nltk==3.7
txtai @ git+https://github.com/neuml/txtai
txtai[pipeline]
Pillow
beautifulsoup4
```

But Heroku gives the following error:
[image]
I tried replacing txtai[pipeline] with git+https://github.com/neuml/txtai#egg=txtai[api,pipeline,workflow] but I received the same error [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyHr6.png)

If I remove `txtai[pipeline]` it gives this error `Compiled slug size: 1G is too large (max is 500M).`

Txtai github: https://github.com/neuml/txtai
How do I include this dependency properly in order to successfully deploy it on Heroku?

Comment: Have you tried deploying in streamlit cloud at https://docs.streamlit.io/streamlit-cloud/get-started/deploy-an-app?

Comment: Yes, but streamit share doesn't provide custom domains.

Comment: Did you experience issues in streamlit cloud?

Comment: No. except the custom domain. No issues